# Why is my whole view animating rather than just my UIImage View

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimageview

Im making a custom alert in storyboards by overlaying a UIImage over my entire view alpha set .5 then another UIImage over that, set initially to hidden.

an `IBAction` then sets these to `hidden = NO`

I have then animated this to simulate the `AlertView` 'bounce" with some code from another post on here.

.m under IBAction

```
tint.hidden = NO; <<tint image

storm.hidden = NO; << my image view

mybtn.hidden = NO; << button to dismiss the view



self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.001, 0.001);
self.view.alpha = 1.0;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(bounce1AnimationStopped)];
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.1, 1.1);
[UIView commitAnimations];


[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(bounce2AnimationStopped)];
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.9, 0.9);
[UIView commitAnimations];



[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

The problem is the WHOLE view animates and bounces inc the view controller underneath, I only want the UIImage `storm` to animate and not the whole screen.

So far I tried changing `Self` to my `UIImage`, and also changing `UIView` to `UIImageview`

Now im out of ideas

Comment: I only see you set `self.view`, you never set `storm` to transform.

Comment: When i changed it to `storm` the image disappeared, stayed hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What object is `storm`? Is it an `UIImage` or `UIImageView`?

If it is `UIImageView`, then just swap all lines from this:

```
self.view.transform
```

to this:

```
self.storm.transform
```

Also don't forget on the .alpha setting, change it to storm also :)

And that should do the trick.

Comment: Then create an UIImageView with property .image set to "storm. and then just change the the lines to "self.YOURUIIMAGEVIEWNAME.transform". This should work. (change the YOURUIIMAGEVIEWNAME to the actual name of your uiimageview)

Comment: Thats got it, I had tried every way except that it seems and also hadn't adjusted it in the second and third blocks of code.  Thanks for your advice.